# Android spinner not displaying

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am having a problem with my spinner. It is not showing any value when i press the spinner in the emulator. I tried viewing many tutorials but could'nt find why the spinner was not working. I tried using the ways mentioned in two different tutorials.

This is my main class which has the apinners

```
package com.example.mylastnight;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class drinkmenu extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drinkmenu);

        Spinner commonnames = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner specialnames = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cname = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.commonmenudisplay);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spname = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.specialmenudisplay);

        commonnames.setAdapter(cname);
        specialnames.setAdapter(spname);


    }

}
```

I also tried using a different approach as was mentioned in the developers page in the android developers page.

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> cname = new ArrayAdapter<String>(drinkmenu.this,R.array.commonmenudisplay,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spname = new ArrayAdapter<String>(drinkmenu.this, R.array.specialmenudisplay,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        cname.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spname.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        commonnames.setAdapter(cname);
        specialnames.setAdapter(spname);


    }

}
```

The arrays xml has a string array which has many items in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
      new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.commonmenudisplay);
```

to:

```
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.commonmenudisplay, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
```